# Issue in Backend camera while capturing the Image

Tags: android, camera

Problem Definition : Here I am try to develope one app which is select image from gallery while user has to click on button and open opt menu like "capture image" and "select from gallery" and that selecting image from either gallery or capture via camera. I try to show that the selected image set button left side(Button left drawable property) as programmatically. While i am try to capture image from front camera then it's work fine. but while i try to use back(rear) camera that time my app going to crash..
What should i do to work with both camera(front+rear)??

[What i needed in output from back camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2VbF.png) 
[on button click open opt menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7XyQ.png)

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CLOSEUP_SMILE = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY_CLOSEUP_SMILE = 2;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        final String[] option = new String[] { "Take from Camera","Select from Gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Option");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Selected Item", String.valueOf(which));
                if (which == 0) {
                    callCamera();
                }
                if (which == 1) {
                    callGallery();
                }

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        btnCloseUpSmile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
               }
        });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_REQUEST_CLOSEUP_SMILE:

        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY_CLOSEUP_SMILE:
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            Uri filePath = data.getData();

            Bitmap bCloseUpSmile=getPath(data.getData());

            int widthCloseUp = bCloseUpSmile.getWidth();
            int heightCloseUp = bCloseUpSmile.getHeight();
            int newWidth = (btnCloseUpSmile.getHeight()/2);
            int newHeight = (btnCloseUpSmile.getHeight()/2);

            // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / widthCloseUp;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / heightCloseUp;

            Matrix matrixCloseUp = new Matrix();
            matrixCloseUp.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            Bitmap resizedBitmapCloseUp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bCloseUpSmile, 36, 36, true);
            Drawable d=(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resizedBitmapCloseUp));
            bitmapForCloseUpSmile = resizedBitmapCloseUp;
            boolCloseUpSmile=true;
            btnCloseUpSmile.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
            selectedImageCloseUpSmile=getStringPathImage(data.getData());
            System.out.println("File Path = "+selectedImageCloseUpSmile);

        break;
}


private Bitmap getPath(Uri uri) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    return bitmap;
}

/**
 * open camera method
 */
// ------------------------------ With Smile Reuest------------------------------------------------------------------
public void callCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CLOSEUP_SMILE);
}

    /**
     * open gallery method
     */
public void callGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),PICK_FROM_GALLERY_CLOSEUP_SMILE);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Crash Log (Errors):

```
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500): Process: com.mayur.demo, PID: 23500
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mayur.demo/com.mayur.demo.ActivityRegistration}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/286844 (has extras) }} to activity {com.mayur.demo/com.mayur.demo.ActivityRegistration}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2996)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3025)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3974)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:166)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/286844 (has extras) }} to activity {com.mayur.demo/com.mayur.demo.ActivityRegistration}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3601)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2983)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    ... 13 more
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:922)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:833)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at com.mayur.demo.ActivityRegistration.onActivityResult(ActivityRegistration.java:515)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5514)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3597)
06-17 18:27:27.051: E/AndroidRuntime(23500):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: post the error crash log

Comment: @sripadRaj. Please see i have updated my question.

Comment: the height and width is returning 0 in your `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: @SripadRaj I know that but what should i do to solve that issue and i am not getting 0 in btnCloseUpSmile.getHeight().?

Comment: @SripadRaj I am try define static final height of btnCloseUpSmile button. but it not shown an image in right side of button.